# makeblastdb creating multiple files of unexpectedly large sizes

Tags: fasta, python, refseq, blastp, makeblastdb

I have a set of 100 amino acid sequences and I want to perform a BLASTP sesrch against the `refseq_protein` database. Accordingly I had set up the standalone version of BLAST (Version 2.11.0+) and downloaded the refseq_protein database from NCBI using the following code

```
wget ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/refseq/release/complete/*.faa.gz
```

The database gets downloaded as 3027 zipped files containing FASTA sequences. I unzipped all these files and concatenated them into a single file `refseq_protein.faa` (which is around 95 GB in size). Now when I run the following Python code

```
from Bio.Blast.Applications import NcbimakeblastdbCommandline
from Bio.Blast.Applications import NcbiblastpCommandline

cline = NcbimakeblastdbCommandline(dbtype = "prot", input_file = "D:\\refseq_protein.faa", out 
= "refseq_protein")

blastp_cline = NcbiblastpCommandline(query = "D:\\DEP_sequences.fasta', db = 
"refseq_protein", evalue = 0.01, outfmt = "7 sseqid evalue qcovs pident")

cline()

response = blastp_cline()
```

the `NcbimakeblastdbCommandline` function keeps creating multiple `.phr`, `.pin`, `.psq` etc files which take up a lot of space (In a demo run it had created ~30GB of these files and was still running). I'm afraid this will exhaust the entire space available on my internal hard drive. I'm wondering if there is a way to estimate the total size of the files which `NcbimakeblastdbCommandline` would create. This will help me in deciding whether or not to switch to an external storage to perform the BLASTP search.

I am aware of the fact that pre-formatted refseq_protein database exists but I'm not sure what value is to be passed in the `db` parameter of the `NcbiblastpCommandline` function, because it asks for the name of the database against which the BLASTP search is to be performed. In the approach that I chose, I had the liberty to set the name of the database.

Any suggestions on how to solve this issue would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to the Bioinformatics site! Hopefully you find the below helpful.

Regarding the creation of a RefSeq protein database locally...as you mentioned, there are pre-made RefSeq BLAST databases available, and looking at the [website](https://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/blast/db/), the current DB (as of 12/27/2021) is roughly 62.9GB compressed - and is probably ~2x larger decompressed, so I’d guess that the database you are constructing manually will be at least 125GB in size - and likely more.

The above is regarding the technical issue you are currently facing - but I'd back up and look closer at what you are trying to do - align the 100 amino acid sequences to RefSeq. Here are some alternatives that may be -much- easier.

1. BLAST your sequences on the [NCBI website](https://blast.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/Blast.cgi?PROGRAM=blastp&PAGE_TYPE=BlastSearch&LINK_LOC=blasthome). This may not be as satisfying as building out your local tools and databases, but may get the job done more efficiently. This of course depends on whether this is a one-off thing, or something you plan to do frequently, in which case a local database may make sense.
2. Download the premade RefSeq BLAST database. You mentioned you were having issues with how to refer to this database (which may be a useful question in and of itself), but generally an alias file exists within the premade database (entitled `refseq_protein.pal`), and calling this file will allow you to BLAST all the separate chunks. So, the command line might be something like this:

```
blastp -db refseq_protein -query amino_acid_100.fa
```

There are a ton more options you may want to use (try `blastp -help`) , but the above should work.

3. Use the `-remote` option in blastp to run from the command line against the NCBI server. The below line should perform the BLAST alignment against the NCBI refseq protein database.

```
blastp -remote -db refseq_protein -query amino_acid_100.fa
```